# Fetching global variable in the next screen gives error

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

i have a json file in my app and in my App.js i am storing it in a global variable like so..

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('langflag').then(
      (value) => {
      if(value == 1){
          global.language = require('../components/atomic/ar.json');
      }else{
          global.language = require('../components/atomic/en.json');
      }
      },
      (error) => setToken({ error })
    );
  }, []);
```

it is setting global variable language but in the immediate next screen i want to show string from this variable it gives "Undefined is not an object" error on this

```
global.language.stringname
```

Comment: please make sure the json file are in right location, immediately after global.language variable setting, try console.log

Comment: i tried no log till i refresh the screen again.